# Styling Compose for Desktop Tray Composable

Tags: system-tray, tray, compose-desktop, compose-multiplatform

I've been playing around with Compose for Desktop, and I am trying to figure out how Jetbrain styled the `Tray` Composable. I am assuming that's what they used to build the Jetbrains Toolbox since they wrote a post about how they migrated the Toolbox to Compose for Desktop [(see here)](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2021/12/compose-multiplatform-toolbox-case-study/).

| Default Tray | Jetbrains Toolbox Tray |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

The images are from Ubuntu 22; I haven't tested Windows or Mac yet.

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Comment: Windows is a similar situation, my own application looks plain, similar to what you see on Linux. But their application's menu looks more like the native Windows ones. (For some definition of native. I guess it looks like a Swing menu with Windows L&F?)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Library : https://github.com/dorkbox/SystemTray

in your gradle file

```
            implementation("net.java.dev.jna:jna:5.14.0")
            implementation("com.dorkbox:SystemTray:4.4")
```

and you can use it like this in your main function :

```
    val tray = SystemTray.get()
    val resource = this::class.java.classLoader.getResource("AppIcon.png")

    tray.setImage(resource)
    val menu = tray.menu

// add a menu item
    menu.add(MenuItem("Item 1") {
        println("Item 1 selected")
    })

// add a checkbox
    menu.add(Checkbox("Checkbox Item") {
        println("Checkbox Item: $it")
    })

// add a separator
    menu.add(Separator())
// add a submenu
    val submenu = Menu("Submenu")
    submenu.add(MenuItem("Subitem 1") {
        println("Subitem 1 selected")
    })
    menu.add(submenu)
```